# Strongswan swanctl.conf parameter syntax

Tags: strongswan, syntax

I am looking for exact syntax for swanctl.conf parameter syntax. I read though the [swanctl.conf documentation](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Swanctlconf), but there does not seem to be any exact syntax for parameters.

Mainly I am looking for the exact way to specify different "proposals"
We are using aes256-sha2;dh20 (syntax from Libreswan), but I am not sure how this translates to swanctl.conf.

Is there some document that details every single parameter syntax for swanctl.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Does not seem to be a specific location on Strong Swan's website with syntax for all parameters in swanctl.conf. However I did find the syntax in this page

https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IKEv2CipherSuites

"aes256-sha256-ecp384"